# Why do “L” and “M” name the strong and weak modal operators in modal logic?

Tags: logic, terminology, modal-logic, symbolic-logic

Though the box and diamond are the more common representations of the strong and weak modal operators in modal logic, “L” and “M” are also used. I suspect that those letters were chosen because they each refer to English or German words, but I can't find any reference that mentions which ones.

Comment: Note that it's common enough to use K in some English texts instead of L. In particular in doxastic-epistemic contexts that's commonly done (and B is the other, usually independent modal in these logics; M and N are used as their duals).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Polish logician and philosopher [Jan Łukasiewicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_%C5%81ukasiewicz) who invented the [Polish notation for logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation#Polish_notation_for_logic) (named after his nationality) :

> **M ϕ** for [*możliwość*](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/polish-english/mo%C5%BCliwo%C5%9B%C4%87) : possibility
>
> **L ϕ** for [*konieczność*](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/polish-english/konieczno%C5%9B%C4%87) : necessity [unfortunately: **K** was alredy used for *koniunkcja* : conjunction].

For **M**, see Jan Lukasiewicz, [Selected works](https://books.google.it/books?id=AOPWAAAAMAAJ), North-Holland (1970), *Philosophical remarks on many-valued systems of propositional logic* (Polish ed., 1920), page 154:

> it is possible that *p*, in symbols *Mp*, [where] "*M*" corresponds to the words "it is possible that".

Łukasiewicz used "**L**" for "it is necessary that" in: [Aristotle Syllogistic From the Standpoint of Modern Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=AgR5AAAAMAAJ) (1st ed, 1951).

But an earlier use is in Robert Feys, [*Les systèmes formalisés des modalités aristotéliciennes*](http://www.persee.fr/docAsPDF/phlou_0035-3841_1950_num_48_20_4310.pdf), *Revue Philosophique de Louvain*, Volume 48 (1950).